# Where can I find firefox log file?

Tags: logs, firefox

Where can I find firefox log file on Centos 6?

Unfortunately, firefox doesn't write its log in `/var/log/message`         .

Comment: Why do you need the logs? Firefox doesn't produce logfiles by default.

Comment: @Braiam to know how the most resource consuming process of machine is going. If there is anything I should pay attention to. Don't know, will be sure if there is something to care about just after see it.

Comment: @wviana for that you don't use logs, you use software monitoring like top, ntop, iotop, etc. After you identify the culprit, then you start poring through other information that the application can produce. I will not be surprised that an application is trashing the disk if it's writing verbose logs to it instead of using the syslog facility.

Answer (score 4):

`firefox` writes to the session log;
on older systems (pre-`systemd`) that's saved in `~/.xsession-errors` so try running:

```
grep firefox ~/.xsession-errors
```

on newer, `systemd`-based setups you can view (as a user) the relevant entries in the *journal* with:

```
journalctl -qb /usr/bin/firefox
```

Comment: been `-q` for quiet and `-b` to show only current boot. But completition doen't even offer to complete the last argument as a path. Couldn't success with journalctl command mentioned in this answer. Maybe there is something to enable on firefox `about:config` page, so it does log into journalctl?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that by "firefox log" you mean all temporary files created by firefox, so have a look at directory `~/.mozilla/firefox`. You may find there subdirectories with cache, "Crash Reports", but also many configuration files (for example `profiles.ini`).